# Available options in the spark.read.option()

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark

When I read other people's python code, like, `spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true")`, it seems that the coder has already known what the parameters to use. But for a starter, is there a place to look up those available parameters? I look up the apche documents and it shows parameter undocumented.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#manually-specifying-options

Comment: Yes. I did. But in all the examples listed, it is like that he/she has already now what the parameters to use, for example, df = spark.read.load("examples/src/main/resources/people.csv",
                     format="csv", sep=":", inferSchema="true", header="true"). But for a starter, how can I know what are the potential key-value pairs that are good to pass.

Answer (score 17):

Annoyingly, the documentation for the `option` method is in the docs for the `json` method. The docs on that method say the options are as follows (key -- value -- description):

- primitivesAsString -- true/false (default false) -- infers all primitive values as a string type
- prefersDecimal -- true/false (default false) -- infers all floating-point values as a decimal type. If the values do not fit in decimal, then it infers them as doubles.
- allowComments -- true/false (default false) -- ignores Java/C++ style comment in JSON records
- allowUnquotedFieldNames -- true/false (default false) -- allows unquoted JSON field names
- allowSingleQuotes -- true/false (default true) -- allows single quotes in addition to double quotes
- allowNumericLeadingZeros -- true/false (default false) -- allows leading zeros in numbers (e.g. 00012)
- allowBackslashEscapingAnyCharacter -- true/false (default false) -- allows accepting quoting of all character using backslash quoting mechanism
- allowUnquotedControlChars -- true/false (default false) -- allows JSON Strings to contain unquoted control characters (ASCII characters with value less than 32, including tab and line feed characters) or not.
- mode -- PERMISSIVE/DROPMALFORMED/FAILFAST (default PERMISSIVE) -- allows a mode for dealing with corrupt records during parsing.

  - PERMISSIVE : when it meets a corrupted record, puts the malformed
    string into a field configured by columnNameOfCorruptRecord, and sets
    other fields to null. To keep corrupt records, an user can set a
    string type field named columnNameOfCorruptRecord in an user-defined
    schema. If a schema does not have the field, it drops corrupt records
    during parsing. When inferring a schema, it implicitly adds a
    columnNameOfCorruptRecord field in an output schema.
  - DROPMALFORMED : ignores the whole corrupted records.
  - FAILFAST : throws an exception when it meets corrupted records.

Comment: Thanks for this! I wouldn't have thought to look at `.json()`. I was hoping for some constants...

Comment: I do not think this is an exhaustive list. For example you can also have ```.option("header",True)```

Answer (score 4):

For built-in formats all options are enumerated in the official documentation. Each format has its own set of option, so you have to refer to the one you use.

- For `read` open docs for [`DataFrameReader`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) and expand docs for individual methods. Let's say for JSON format expand `json` method (only one variant contains full list of options)

  [json options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSzhd.png)
- For write open docs for [`DataFrameWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter). For example for Parquet:

  [parquet options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zstaq.png)

However merging schema is performed not via options, but using session properties

```
 spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", "true")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is, for example, def
option(key: String, value: Double): DataFrameReader
 Permalink
Adds an input option for the underlying data source.

Since
2.0.0  How Can I find all available key-value pairs.

Comment: What about CSV options?

Answer (score 4):

You can get from here

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html

change the highlighted part to get the version you are looking for.

Comment: You should more clearly explain the answer from the link in case the link changes or goes dead.

Comment: The link above refers to the SPARK API which will have the latest information always.

Comment: @H R I'm sure the link is helpful, and you can explain that to a moderator, because I wasn't about to getting flagged for screwing up a review of a link only answer again.

Comment: That documentation is dense and not helpful. Can we just get an explanation? Stack overflow doesn't exist because all documentation is perfect and no one has questions.

Comment: the documentation about `option(String key, String value)` says : key - (undocumented). Not very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can find them here. Look for "Data Source Option" section.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#data-source-option

There are support documents for each file type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

More options you will find in the [Spark API Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) of the method `csv` of class `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader`. As shown above, the options depend on the input format to be read.